# Fetch local resource on PHP server

Tags: php, reactjs, jwt, cors, localhost

I'm developing a small barebones PHP backend (no frameworks) and a frontend app on React as an exercise. Pretty basic stuff, some components on the React app that calls routes on the PHP backend API through useEffect hook with a fetch request.

Everything was going ok but I ran into some troubles with an authenticated request that uses a JWT. I'm running the PHP server with the built-in PHP server (php -S localhost:8080). This is the request i'm sending:

```
    const fetchHeader = {
        headers: {
            "Authorization": 'Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpZCI6MiwibmFtZSI6IlNyIENsaWVudGUiLCJlbWFpbCI6ImNsaWVudEBtYWlsLmNvbSIsImNyZWF0ZWQiOiIyMDIzLTEwLTExIDIwOjE1OjM1Iiwicm9sZSI6IkNMSUVOVCJ9.5m_IOjFa_DeTwzIeZk5adhQQY5O_PYrVpcR2StbwUas',
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/cart/current', { fetchHeader, crossDomain: true, method: 'GET' })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
            console.log(data)
            //setOrder(data.content);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err.message);
        });
    }, []);
```

On the server, I added this to print the headers, just for debug sake:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *");
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
$headers = getallheaders();
$headers['X-Control_Property'] = 'X-Control_Property';
ksort($headers);
echo json_encode($headers, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
die();
```

Using Postman everything is fine, as the authorization is being sent successfully:

[image: Postman]

But I notice that the output on server side is a bit different

[image: client]

For some reason the Authentication apparently is not being sent. I'm stuck on this for quite some time now, searched a lot for solutions and tried almost anything I've found, like setting the proxy on package.json, the http-proxy-middleware stuff and different combinations of headers configuration, but I'm out of ideas.

Comment: `{ fetchHeader, crossDomain: true, method: 'GET' }` is not what you think it is. Try `{ headers: fetchHeader.headers, crossDomain: true, method: 'GET' }` instead.

Comment: Yeah, tried that too, it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

On the surface this doesn't make much sense...Bearer Tokens should only sent over HTTPS (SSL) but you are using HTTP.

Also, in your fetch request, you have set `crossDomain: true` AFAIK this is not a valid option for the fetch API. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Looking at it you should have `credentials` set to `include`, e.g.

```
    fetch('https://localhost:8080/api/cart/current', {
        headers: {
            "Authorization": 'Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpZCI6MiwibmFtZSI6IlNyIENsaWVudGUiLCJlbWFpbCI6ImNsaWVudEBtYWlsLmNvbSIsImNyZWF0ZWQiOiIyMDIzLTEwLTExIDIwOjE1OjM1Iiwicm9sZSI6IkNMSUVOVCJ9.5m_IOjFa_DeTwzIeZk5adhQQY5O_PYrVpcR2StbwUas',
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        credentials: 'include', // Include credentials with the request
        method: 'GET'
    })
```

So, really you should to modify your fetch and use HTTPS (SSL) for Bearer authentication to work as expected/intended.

Comment: Yeah but for instance, if i fill the header with just some dummy data like this

`fetch(url, { header: { dummy: 'dummy' } })`

if i print the headers on the server, that dummy key value wont show up. So it seems like the react side of things is not properly setting up the headers or are reseting it, i really dont know

Comment: @paulie_g - Well in your simple `fetch(url, { header: { dummy: 'dummy' } })`  example you have a typo... it should be `headers` not `header` - so clearly that won't work.